# Mac command line - run command if previous has failed

Tags: command-line, bash, python, macosx

On my **mac** run scripts that take a long time and for this reason I add `&& say done` so that I can hear when the script has finished running while I am doing other things around the house. However, sometimes my code has bugs/typos and so it throws an error. This results in the script interrupting but not saying anything.

> Is there something I can add to the command below that will execute even if the command fails?

#### Current Command

```
python3 script.py && say done
```

#### Suggested command

I would like something like this

```
python3 script.py && say done otherwise-if-script-failed say failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the boolean-OR operator

```sh
python3 script.py && say done || say failed
```

One thing to note about that style: in `A && B || C`, `C` will execute if `A` fails **or** if `B` fails. The safer way to write that is

```sh
if python3 script.py; then say done; else say failed; fi
```